# Does Chrome automatically recognize node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

If I create a Javascript file called server.js containing just the following code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    //debugger;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

and have no other files in the directory (no html or other javascript code) and then run the following command:

```
devtool server.js --watch
```

the Chrome debugger window launches. I can then put a breakpoint within the code. Then in my browser, if I navigate to localhost:8888, my breakpoint will hit.

I have node.js installed. My question is how Chrome even knows what the require("http") even is as I have no dependencies nor am I referencing the requirejs library. So how is it that Chrome is able to run this node.js code? Does Chrome somehow know that node.js is installed?

Comment: Erm... running node.js through the Chrome developer tools is what devtool does... I'm not sure what the question is

Comment: Turns out that devtool is not a Google thing as I assumed. It's a tool that runs node.js code through the Chrome debugging tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using the *devtool* tool, which must be [this devtool](https://github.com/Jam3/devtool) ?

It communicates the code to the browser, for you to debug it, and translates it into browser executable code using *browserify*.

*devtool* knows that it is some node.js code, Chrome does not.